# Quest system with prerequisites

Tags: php, mysql

I'm coding a quest system for my site that pretty much works like any you find in an MMORPG. I've got the whole thing working, but I really need to speed things up since I coded it inefficiently. Not because I can't code, but because I just wasn't sure how to go about it.

Basically I want to display all the quests that are available to the user. There are quests with no requirements, and some with. To see if a quest has already been completed, and a quest is available you would check the questuser table for the value of questuserCompleted. If it's 1, then it's complete.

Here are the tables I have. I left irrelevant things out.

quest table - Holds all the quest data

```
questID
questNPC
    Where they get the Quest from
questPreReq
    refers to a quest they would have needed to comple to get this one
```

questuser table - Holds all the quests the user has accepted, complete or not

```
questuserID
questuserUser
    User's ID
questuserQuest
    refers to the ID of the quest from the quest table
questuserCompleted
    0 is in progress, 1 is complete
```

There's definitely a better way to do than I have now. I'm usually more efficient at things like this, but since I've never coded something like this before, I'm not really sure how to go about it.

Basically it just loops through every single quest, and with an if statement, it checks for questuserCompleted. Once there starts to be a lot of quests, this would get pretty slow for each load of the page.

```
    function displayAvailable($npc  = 0){

    $completed[] = 0;
    $notCompleted = array();
        $query=mysql_query("
        SELECT a.questID, a.questPreReq, a.questTitle, b.questuserCompleted, a.questText , a.questNPC  
        FROM quest a 
        LEFT JOIN questuser b ON a.questID = b.questuserQuest AND b.questuserUser = '".$this->userID."' 
        ORDER BY a.questID");

        $comments =  $this->ProcessRowSet($query);
        $num = mysql_num_rows($query);
        if($num){
             foreach ($comments as $c){
             if($c['questuserCompleted']){
                $completed[] = $c['questID'];
             }else{
                $notCompleted[] = $c['questID'];
             }

             if(in_array($c['questPreReq'], $completed) && !in_array($c['questID'], $completed) && $c['questuserCompleted'] != '0'){
                 if($npc == 0 || $c['questNPC'] == $npc){
                    $count++;
                        $return .= "<p><a href=\"?action=new&id=".$c['questID']."\">".$c['questTitle']."</a></p>";
                 }
             }
             }
        }
        if(!$count){
            $return = "You have no available quests";
        }
        return $return;
    }
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Subqueries to the rescue

```
SELECT a.questID, a.questPreReq, a.questTitle, a.questText , a.questNPC
FROM quest a 
WHERE a.questPreReq IS NULL
OR a.questPreReq IN (SELECT questuserQuest FROM questuser WHERE questuserUser = 'UserID' AND questuseCompleted = 1) 
ORDER BY a.questID
```

So you let the database sort it out for you, this should be superfast.

The query is missing the exclusion of quests the user already did, I leave this as an exercise as I am writing on my smartphone ; )

Comment: Why didn't I know these existed? Time to read everything possible about them.

Thanks so much!